# State variable inside a function defined within useEffect hook is not updating when value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a project where I need to measure the height of DOM elements, then set that value in a `useState` hook and finally use the state value in a `useEffect` hook. However, the value that I define in `useState` (named `maxTranslate`) is used within a function. Even though I add `maxTranslate` as a dependency to `useEffect`, the value of `maxTranslate` inside the function does not change from its initial value of `-440`. I can confirm that the `useEffect` is being triggered on `maxTranslate` state change though.

I obviously think this has to do with stale closures but since it is re-rendering, I'm not quite sure why. What am I missing?

I first define a `useState`:

```
// state variable that defines a default maxTranslate value
const [maxTranslate, setMaxTranslate] = useState(-440)
```

Here I define a `useEffect` that takes in 3 DOM refs and calculates their `getBoundingClientRect().height`

```
// useEffect to calculate the height of 3 DOM elements
// please let me know if there there's a better semantic way of doing something like this

useEffect(() => {
      setMaxTranslate((-1 * ((pageSize?.height || 0) - (previewSize?.height || 0) - (headerSize?.height || 0))))
  }, [pageSize, previewSize, headerSize])
```

Next, is my `useEffect` that takes in `maxTranslate` as a dependency. I can `console.log` the `maxTranslate` in here and confirm that the value updates properly.

```
// when maxTranslate changes from the useEffect above, the useEffect below will fire again
useEffect(() => {

let started: boolean = false;
let initialStep: number = 0;

const square = Array.from(animationEl.current!.nodes.values())[0];

const swipeGesture = createGesture({
    el: square,
    gestureName: 'swipeGesture',
    direction: 'y',
    threshold: 0,
    onMove: (ev) => onMove(ev),
    onEnd: (ev) => onEnd(ev),
});
swipeGesture.enable(true);

const onMove = (ev: GestureDetail) => {
    if (!started) {
    setProgressStart({ forceLinearEasing: true });
    started = true;
    }
    setProgressStep({ step: getStep(ev) });
};

const onEnd = (ev: GestureDetail) => {
    if (!started) {
    return;
    }

    swipeGesture.enable(false);

    const step = getStep(ev);
    const shouldComplete = step > 0.25;

    setProgressEnd({ playTo: shouldComplete ? 1 : 0, step });

    setOnFinish({
    callback: () => {
        swipeGesture!.enable(true);
        setProgressStart(undefined);
        setProgressStep(undefined);
        setProgressEnd(undefined);
    },
    opts: { oneTimeCallback: true },
    });

    initialStep = shouldComplete ? maxTranslate : 0;
    started = false;
};


const getStep = (ev: GestureDetail) => {
    const delta = initialStep + ev.deltaY;
      // THIS VALUE OF maxTranslate DOES NOT CHANGE FROM THE INITIAL VALUE OF -440 THOUGH!
    return clamp(0, delta / maxTranslate, 1);
};

}, [animationEl, maxTranslate]);
```

My `getStep` function should be getting redefined once the page re-renders and closes over the scope of the most recent value of `maxTranslate`, correct? What's going on here? Thanks!

---

EDIT: added full useEffect

Comment: Where and how do you use getStep

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I went ahead and edited the `useEffect` to show the entire callback, `getStep` is used in `onMove` and `onEnd` and then assigned in my `swipeGesture`

Comment: You don't seem to disable the gesture as part of cleanup in useEffect. Probably your old function also gets executed along with the new one

Comment: you are spot on, I added `    return () => { swipeGesture.destroy(); }` and now it works. If you add that as an answer, I'll mark as correct. I'm confused though, I thought when the useEffect re-fires, it forgets the old `swipeGesture` and reassigns with the new values. In your answer post could you explain that a little more? Thanks! Edit: maybe because swipeGesture is some sort of event listener and those don't get destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you **aren't cleaning up the previous listeners** created with createGesture when the useEffect runs again due to change in maxTranslate value

So when you don't do that, even though the component isn't needing those old listeners they still do continue to exist and are not garbage collected since their reference in not lost

Hence the getStep method was called with old value as it fired for the previous listener

Its always advices that you clear your subscriptions and listeners in cleanup function of useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
   ...
   return () => {
        swipeGesture.destroy();
   }

}, [animationEl, maxTranslate])
```